# In Xamarin.Forms Getting Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed

Tags: service, xamarin, dependencies

I am getting exception unity dependency exception for my custom service. I have integrated sqllite to store my data locally. And here is my code:

```
public interface IDatabaseConnection
    {
        SQLite.SQLiteConnection DbConnection();
    }
```

and here is my service implementation:

```
public class UsersDataAccess
    {
    public UsersDataAccess()
            {
                database =
                  DependencyService.Get<IDatabaseConnection>().
                  DbConnection();

            }
}
```

I am calling this into my viewmodel:

```
 public class TestViewModel : BindableBase
    {
    private UsersDataAccess _userDataAccess;

    public TestViewModel ()
        {
            _userDataAccess = new UsersDataAccess();
        }
    }
```

for android app it is working good, but when I try to build for ios it is getting exception for unity dependency service failed to load like below:

Unhandled Exception:
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "TestViewModel ", name = "(none)".

Exception occurred while: Calling constructor TestViewModel ().

### Exception is: NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

At the time of the exception, the container was:
  Resolving TestViewModel ,(none)
  Calling constructor TestViewModel ()

on my app.cs file I have only added another custom service dependency on unity register type :

```
UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterType<IUserService, UserService>(Container);
```

But not for IDatabaseConnection because that is getting by implementation 
like:

```
DependencyService.Get<IDatabaseConnection>()
```

What I have done wrong here?

Comment: use try catch in your constructors, you will get the actual error. basically the error means the object could not be created.

Comment: Hi, thank you, I have sorted out the problem, I forgot to implement the interface but done well for android and this is why it was working good the android version, now ios version also working good like a charm :)